# Get Path to Subdirectory in Resources Folder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, resources, path

i'm trying to get an array of all png files in a subdirectory of the Resources Folder.
In my apps Resources Folder I have created a Folder named "images". This folder holds all the png-files I need to display.

This is the way I tried to get the Path:

```
    NSString *imagepath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath],@"images/"];

NSLog(@"Path to Images: %@", imagepath);

NSArray * paths = [NSBundle pathsForResourcesOfType: @"png" inDirectory:imagepath];
NSMutableArray * allImageNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for ( NSString * path in paths )
{
    if ( [[path lastPathComponent] hasPrefix: @"AQ"] )
        continue;

    [allImageNames addObject: [path lastPathComponent]];
}
```

This way I get a Path like …/appname.app/images

But if i try to do it that way, the array is always empty. 
What am I doing wrong?

greetz,
Zarak

Comment: What are you images names? Are they like `image.AQ`?

Comment: The image names are like  "banana_icon.png". But I use the AQGridView to create a gallery of all files.

Comment: Then why do you check `[[path lastPathComponent] hasPrefix: @"AQ"] `?

Comment: Are you sure the images are in a separate folder not just a 'group' within Resources in your Xcode project?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just solved it.

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSArray *pngs = [mainBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@".png"
 inDirectory:@"random pictures"];

 NSLog(@"pngs in my dir:%@", pngs);
```

dir structure: "Resources/random pictures".

This works, BUT, when you add the files to 'Resources', you need to check "**Create folder references for any aded folders**", and NOT "Create groups for any added folders".

[image: important step]

Cheers!

Comment: Solved the problem by using another solution, but i'll keep this in mind and give it a try in another project. Long story short, you get the accept. ;) Thx for your reply.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I have a folder In-Work with pdf files, I am trying to access the files using:     NSString *inWorkPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"In-Work"];NSArray *resContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:inWorkPath error:&error]; and resContents return nil

Comment: did you check "Create folder references" when adding the folder to the project? @EshwarChaitanya

Comment: @codrut Oops, it was my mistake. Like you said, I didn't check Create folder references while copying the resources.