# Accessing all images in a folder iphone Application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsfilemanager

I am making an iPhone app using Xcode and following is the directory structure

```
GFGGAME
  -gfggame.xcodeproj
  -Images
    --bagold
     ---bags_1.png
     ---bags_2.png
    --bagsnew
     ---bags_5.png
     ---bags_6.png
```

I want to access all images from folder `bagsold` and `bagsnew` . If I use resource path and a predicate filter for png it gives me all the png files . Is there a way i can access just the files present in the folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you probably want to use this `NSBundle` method:

```objc
+ (NSArray *)pathsForResourcesOfType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)bundlePath
```

[See API docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You would pass `@".png"` as your extension, and then specify the directory path just for the subdirectories you want (you might need to call this twice, one for each subdirectory, and then just append the second array of paths to the first).

[See a similar question on Stack Overflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8743760/119114)

**Note** the point in the answer (link) above, about what you need to do in Xcode to make this work.

Comment: NSString* bundlePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Images"];
    NSArray* files = [NSBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@".png" inDirectory:bundlePath];
    
    for ( NSString* fn in files)
        NSLog(@"%@",fn);

This is returning me no images. Where as if I don't append images to the resource path I get all the images in all folders

Comment: @ila, I think you have an extra slash (`/`) in your path (`@"/Images"`) ... although that *probably* doesn't hurt. Also, did you note the comment at the end of the answer I linked to (where he says "BUT ...")? Did you do that?

Answer (score 3):

From your responses to the other people who have answered, it sounds to me like you've confused folders with Xcode groups.  Xcode groups do not correspond to folders on the device.  They are solely there to help you keep your Xcode project organised for *you*, not the device.  Any resources just get copied straight into the main directory bundle with a flat hierarchy.

When you drag a folder into Xcode to add it to a project, you need to select *"Create folder references for any added folders"* and **not** *"Create groups for any added folders"*.  This will preserve the directory layout when the application is built.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
NSString *bundleRootpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *filePath = [bundleRootpath pathForResource:@"bags_1" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Images/bagold"]
NSFileManager *fileMangr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *dirContents = [fileMangr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRootpath error:nil]; //your path here it may be document directory also
```

Filter JPG if any

```
NSArray *onlyJPGs;
if([dirContents count] > 0){
NSPredicate *fltrJPG = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.jpg'"];
onlyJPGs = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltrJPG];
}
```

Now PNG if any

```
NSArray *onlyPNGs;
if([dirContents count] > 0){
NSPredicate *fltrPNG = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.png'"];
onlyPNGs = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltrPNG];
```

Search for any other format if any

Merge onlyJPGs and onlyPNGs into one array

Comment: I am having a problem getting path to the Images/bagsold folder. How can I get that ?

Answer (score 1):

Just for variety :)

```
   NSMutableArray *filePaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[NSBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:nil inDirectory:fullPathToFolder]];
    NSMutableArray *toDelete = [NSMutableArray array];
    if(filePaths.count>0){
        [filePaths enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if(!([obj hasSuffix:@"jpg"] || [obj hasSuffix:@"png"])){
                    [toDelete addObject:obj];
            }
        }];
    }
    [filePaths removeObjectsInArray:toDelete];
    return filePaths;
```