# Include external JavaScript file in the WebView of React Native App

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to include an external JavaScript file inside a **WebView** of my React Native project. The file I wish to include is a third party library not available on `npm` written in plain JavaScript (No ES5 or higher). I need a solution for injecting my JS file in the WebView of the React Native project without importing it or making it an npm module.

I have tried the following methods but nothing works as for now:

- I have tried to load the script like this: [Insert script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)
- I have tried to load the script dynamically in `injectedJavaScript` following the answer here: [Link JS file from a JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

This is my external `AppGeneral.js`:

```
function AppGeneral(){
     alert("Ok");
}
var app = new AppGeneral();
```

This is my `index.ios.js` file:

```
export default class sampleReactApp extends Component {
  render() {

    let HTML = `
    <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/AppGeneral.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="workbookControl"></div>
            <div id="tableeditor">editor goes here</div>
            <div id="msg" onclick="this.innerHTML='&nbsp;';"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
    `;

     let jsCode = `
     alert("Js");
    `;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <WebView
                style={styles.webView}
                ref="myWebView"
                source={{ html: HTML }}
                injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
                javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
            >
            </WebView>
        </View>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use the webview to execute code?

Comment: @MartinCup My JS file is a JS Spreadsheet engine. Converting the entire library into a module and then using it in the import statement would not be the optimal solution. Therefore, I wanted to include this file as it is done in a *cordova* based app i.e in the webview. Kindly suggest the best approach.

Comment: @Manu Gupta - did you find a way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 8):

The only way to load JavaScript in a RN WebView is using the `injectedJavaScript` property, and this can only take a plain string (not a file path). In my case, I've done it this way:

First generate a file that contains your JS file converted to a plain string:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const filePath = '/path/to/your/lib.js';
const js = await fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8');
const json = 'module.exports = ' + JSON.stringify(js) + ';';
await fs.writeFile('/my-rn-app/external-lib.js', json);
```

And make sure "/my-rn-app/external-lib.js" is somewhere where it can be imported in React Native.

Then simply import the file and inject it in the WebView:

```
const myJsLib = require('external-lib.js');
const webView = <WebView injectedJavaScript={myJsLib} .....
```

This is not a particularly pretty solution but it works well.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try bundling your JS file as an asset and then refer to the file as you would in a 'native' WebView. Have a look at this answer for [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9432330/2628463) and this ones for iOS, [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436281/2628463)] and [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12904900/2628463)].

Comment: I, as well, think this is the solution

Answer (score 0):

I ended up pasting the js source code around `<script> my js code ... <script/>` tags