# Load local image file from within WebView

Tags: webview, react-native

I have a React Native `WebView` that runs a small HTML document. The document shows a few images.

My hope is to show images located in the app's *Documents* folder, i.e. the images are *not* static assets, but are downloaded by the app at runtime and stored on disk. These images are then referenced from HTML running inside a React Native `WebView`.

This is what I have tried so far:

### Sourcing the file directly

I have tried sourcing the file from within the `WebView` which does not work (404 Not Found):

#### 1. Simulator

> ::1 - - [25/Nov/2016:09:55:52 +0000] "GET /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/43707753-69A2-4EC7-B990-F7910A853F42/data/Containers/Data/Application/E4F4A368-02B0-4BAE-BEB3-BDF0FF7ADDDF/Documents/1657.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 193 "http://localhost:8081/assets/src/index.html?platform=ios&hash=8cb6d49177b95c46ed6654eb038a9a8d" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.2.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14B72"

#### 2. Phone

> ::ffff:192.168.100.143 - - [25/Nov/2016:11:58:31 +0000] "GET /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/970B3033-4AB1-48CF-AFC9-D30534D30BCE/Documents/1657.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 108 "http://192.168.100.114.xip.io:8081/assets/src/index.html?platform=ios&hash=8cb6d49177b95c46ed6654eb038a9a8d" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.2.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14B100"

Seeing as I think this is the correct path (for iOS at least), I think it might be a permissions problem, although unsure.

Comment: Can you update your question to provide a sample of the HTML you're using to reference the images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the docs for React Native `WebView` component, the [`source`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#source) property has two modes:

1. Load a URI
2. Load a static HTML string
3. The result of a call to `require(some.html)`

In the second case it is possible to specify a `baseUrl`. If you set the `baseUrl` to the directory into which images are downloaded, you should be able to reference them by using `<img src="./your-image.png" />`.

#### Post-answer edit: Clarification regarding external HTML

Sadly there is no way to specify a base URL in cases 1 and 3, so you have to first convert it to a string which can be passed to the `source` property. If your HTML refers some external Javascript, you have to get a reference to the bundle directory path, which is where those files have to be to be readable by your app, and reference them relative to that path.

EDIT: This refers to React Native 0.38

Comment: Not sure why but this actually works! Setting `baseUrl` is the key.

Comment: Where do you putted the assets so they could be loaded?

Comment: You need to set the prop allowFileAccess={true} in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your project structure follows the `assets/src...` structure that you are trying to retrieve. The RN packager does not expose your project at all, it simply packs the transpiled bundle (several, actually, varying on platform and debug/release mode) and offers it for download. Event if this worked, it wouldn't help you much once your application goes live. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40794763/2628463) might cover your usecase.

Comment: I'm not wishing to reference any bundled static assets. The React Native app that contains the `WebView` will download various images and place them in the *Documents* folder (each app has its own). What I need is to know how to let the WebView point to such dynamic resources - if need be I could try placing them somewhere else.

Comment: @plougsgaard did you ever figure it out?  I'm struggling with this now